# Keyboard layout doesn't match selected layout

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, keyboard-layout

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.01

When typing in Chrome, the layout doesn't match what I have selected, I have just one layout English (Programmer Dvorak) configured, however when pressing the physical "asdf", I get "asdf" instead of "aoeu".

This just affects Chrome, all other applications aren't affected.

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard

XKBLAYOUT=us
XKBVARIANT=dvp
BACKSPACE=guess
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the following line in my .bashrc file

```
setxkbmap -option keypad:atm
```

Which would flip the keypad, but reset the keyboard layout, to fix this I then just use:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant dvp -option keypad:atm
```

Which gives me exactly what I need.